# Error Installling an OS in Virtual Box in Ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

While I am trying to install Kali-Linux on Virtual Box in Ubuntu I am getting this error.

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Kali-Linux-1.1.0.
VT-x is disabled in the BIOS. (VERR_VMX_MSR_VMXON_DISABLED).
```

Can anyone help me to sort out this error?

Comment: Did you enable **Intel Virtualization Technology** in your BIOS/UEFI setup?

Comment: @Helio how to do that?

Comment: Shut down the computer. Now press the power button. A image with the computer manufacturer's logo will appear, now keep **F2** pressed. On this menu, dig into the options until you encounter **Intel Virtualization Technology** (or something like), enable it, then **Exit saving changes** and try again.

Answer (score 1):

As per the comment, you should first try to toggle the setting within BIOS.

The BIOS is a special program hardwired into your computer which you can access by pressing the appropriate keys (usually F2 or delete) during the first few seconds of startup--and before the OS itself starts.

Once you get into the BIOS, you need to try and look the setting within the BIOS menus. If you haven't done this sort of thing before, you may find it a bit daunting at first.

Anyway, give it a good attempt. See, how you go.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your BIOS manufacturer:

Restart your computer and open the BIOS settings (eg. press <kbd>F2</kbd> during the start). The setting for VT-x (Intel Virtualization Technology) is often to find under the menu item *Security* or *CPU Configuration*.

If <kbd>F2</kbd> doesn't work try this keys: <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>DEL</kbd>, <kbd>ESC</kbd>